# Why we can't define more mathematical constant?

Tags: math-history, constants

I would like to know how many mathematical constant are there? I saw this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_constant) and I know the names.

- Who can define a mathematical constant?

  - Someone can say that $\int_{x=0}^{1}e^{-\cos(x)}dx\sim.435351$ is called $\hat o$ and it is a new mathematical constant?
- Are there mathematical constant that are not useful?
- And what are the most important mathematical constants?

Comment: Sure you can define whatever mathematical constants you want. There are quite a lot of them ;). Some are more useful than others. Utility often comes in the form of application though. Even $e$ and $\pi$ are not that special as numbers, but where they appear in nature and across many problems in mathematics. The zeroes of the Bessel functions have been computed and there are tables and tables of them but outside of that very narrow context, they aren't special by any means. I guess the long and short of it is that unless there is a utility of the constant (to application), it's likely useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\pi$, $e$, $\gamma$ (Euler's Constant) stand out as some of the more important mathematical constants. If we wanted we could declare any real number as a ``mathematical constant". However, the numbers that bear that name have been found useful in some context, and most commonly they have been found useful in many contexts.

So the answer to your second question is: there are not any "mathematical constants" that are not useful.

The answer to your first question is that the community defines mathematical constants. Generally people who work in a field notice that a number is useful and is appearing frequently and that is how a number comes about as a "mathematical constant".